# Include year in legend (ggplot) but counts as continuous?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to include year as a colour for the points, but for some reason, it shows year with .0 and .5 in the legend, and unsure how to fix. I think it's trying to treat my years as continuous (?) but unsure.

Here's a picture of the plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKgXg.png

And the code:

```
ggplot(data = weather1, aes(x = avgt30, y = dsi, colour = year(date))) +
      theme_bw() +
      geom_count() +
      scale_colour_viridis_c( end = 0.8) +
      scale_y_continuous(trans = "log1p") + 
      stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), colour = "orange") + 
      labs(
        x = "Temperature (\u00B0C)",
        y = "Disease Severity Index",
        title = "DSI vs. Mean 30-day Temp"
      )
```

Similarly, when I try to make the colour = site (caterogy), I get the following error:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Comment: Yes, you have colour mapped to `year(date)`, which will be a continuous numeric variable, and you have `scale_colour_viridis_c()`, which specifies what color range your continuous (ie `*_c`) variable should use. You have two main options -- change the breaks and labels in your color scale, or change the year into a discrete variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, we don't have your data, but we can replicate your problem with a toy data set:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(year = 2011:2020, x = 1:10, y = sin(1:10))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = year)) + 
  geom_point()

p
```

[image]

The easiest way round this is to set the breaks for the color scale, ensuring that all the breaks are integer values:

```r
p + scale_color_continuous(breaks = seq(2011, 2020, 2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>